# How to sync scroll of 2 Appbar layout and Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Activity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coord"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlwaysCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#BDBDBD"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
​

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Fragment xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <NestedCoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e3e6e8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="24dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/shade_gradient" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/simple.viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

     </NestedCoordinatorLayout>
```

When the appbar layout in fragment scrolls, the appbar layout of the activity also should scroll.

Currently when the touch is on the view pager in the fragment, both appbar scroll together, but when the touch is on the appbar of the fragment, only the appbar of fragment scrolls